# Task On time - list search and evaluation

Tags: excel

Consider this data:

```
Project  Name      Due         Completed
P1       T1        04/10/14    04/10/14
P1       T2        05/10/14    06/10/14
P2      T22        07/10/14    07/10/14
P1       T3        17/10/14
```

Is there a formula that can look at this list and pick out all the P1's and evaluate the dates to work out whether they were completed on time. I.E. the data above should produce no as the second task was completed late.

Comment: SO is not a code-on-request site. I'll point you  in the right direction: `Pivot Table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns A - D, add your Project name to cell E1, and enter this as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=IF(MAX(IF($A:$A=E$1,$D:$D-$C:$C))>0,"no","yes")
```

Output:

[image]

**How it works**

Excel stores dates as numbers, so you can subtract one date from another.

Here, I'm subtracting `Due` from `Completed`:

[image]

If the result is a positive number (row 3), the project was completed late.  The negative number occurs because a blank cell is treated as 0 when doing calculations.  Oct 17, 2014 is stored by Excel as the number 41929, so 0 - 41929 = -41929.

This part of the array formula compares each project in column A to the project name in E1, and it returns an array of the results:

```
IF($A:$A=E$1,$D:$D-$C:$C)
```

In our example, the array looks like this:  {0,1,-41929}

The `MAX` function takes the maximum value from the array – in this case the number 1.

The outer `IF` function tests if `MAX`'s result is greater than 0, which would indicate that the project was completed late.  If so, it returns "no."  Otherwise, it returns "yes."